# ItemTemplate with call to Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

What I am trying to do is to call a method from within ItemTemplate.
I have the following:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFixtureType" runat="server" Text='<%# FixtureType(DataBinder.Eval("FixtureType")) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

What I like to do is to pass the value of FixtureType and then append "A" after it. I get the following message: No overload for method 'Eval' takes 1 arguments

```
protected string FixtureType(int FixtureType)
{
  return Convert.ToString(FixtureType) + "A";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't with your method, the error is in the call to `DataBinder.Eval()`.  (The call stack never reaches your method because it fails to evaluate the argument to your method first.)  As indicated by the error, `Eval()` [doesn't have an overload which accepts only one argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval.aspx).

Maybe you mean this?:

```
FixtureType(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FixtureType"))
```

Aside from that, there's a good chance you'll want to put some type checking in place.  `DataBinder.Eval()` returns an `object` and your method expects an `int`.  You'll probably want to either convert the value to an `int` before passing it to your method, or change your method to accept an `object` and then convert it to an `int` internally.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following syntax & updating the signature of your method to take in an `object` instead of an `int`.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFixtureType" runat="server" Text='<%#FixtureType(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FixtureType")) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

protected bool FixtureType(object FixtureType)
{
  return Convert.ToString(FixtureType) + "A";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFixtureType" runat="server" Text='<%# FixtureType(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("FixtureType"))) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

or

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFixtureType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FixtureType").ToString() + "A" %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

or

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFixtureType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FixtureType", "{0}A") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```